# API level 19 not supported for Wear apps?

Tags: android, wear-os

Fresh start with Android Studio, I created a new Project and added checked both Phone and Tablet and Wear. I chose MinSDK 19 for mobile and 20 for Wear (there is no option here). As I try to compile and run this project on my phone (Running 4.4.4 API Level 19), it just fails with the error INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK.
I have tried all possible permutation-combinations of API levels for the Mobile/Wear projects but I can't get it either compile/run on the device.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot put your app as SDK 20, that needs to go in your wear app, leave your main app at 19